# TestCafe React input file type causing error

Tags: reactjs, testcafe

I have a React div on my JSX file like this:

```html
<div>
  <label htmlFor="getFile">
    <input
      id="getFile"
      className="hidden"
      type="file"
      onChange={upload}
      accept="image/*"
    />
    Browse
  </label>
</div>
```

If I have the `type="file"` browsing to this page on TestCafe throws this error :

```
Unhandled Thrown Error!
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parent')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parent')
    at getTopSameDomainWindow (http://localhost:63156/hammerhead.js:3491:33)
    at get (http://localhost:63156/hammerhead.js:19457:32)
    at UploadSandbox._getCurrentInfoManager (http://localhost:63156/hammerhead.js:19489:17)
    at UploadSandbox.getUploadElementValue (http://localhost:63156/hammerhead.js:19535:31)
    at HTMLInputElement.getter [as value] (http://localhost:63156/hammerhead.js:20816:43)
```

Removing the type property fixes this issue. The page works fine when not browsing.

Comment: Looks similar to the following: [GitHub - TestCafe - Issue #7860](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7860).